# Creating a multi-dimensial array from data in three tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my MySQL database and I'm looking to retrieve all the data from each of them and store it in a respective array.
How can I do this without using three separate SQL queries, e.g.

```
$table1_array = "SELECT fid FROM table1" ...;
$table2_array = "SELECT * FROM table2" ...;
$table3_array = "SELECT * FROM table2" ...;
```

I need to perform one query ideally to keep performance up.

**Edit:**

Here is a break down of my table structure:

```
table_photos
pid, aid, caption, src, filename

table_albums
aid, created, count, name

table_feed
fid, timestamp, message, link, caption, description, type, name, pic_src, type, 
filename
```

Thanks

Comment: The tables don't share similar columns and aren't particularly related.

Comment: @lowe_22 If the tables have different structures, do they at least have the same number of columns or nearly so?

Comment: Honestly, I would just do this as three separate queries.  The most expensive operations will be the fetch loops.  However, I wouldn't even worry about it until it becomes a problem. If it doesn't scale and you cannot meet your performance requirement, then worry about doing something tricky with the query.  But wait until there is solid evidence of bad performance before doing something weird to UNION three totally unrelated tables.

Comment: @Jason McCreary, I wasn't sure, thanks :) try with `JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`... If you can't combine them using "normal" way, that means you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: `UNION` would be used when the count of the number of columns is equal, which is not the case here.

Comment: You've mentioned 'multi dimensional' array - what sort of multi dimensional array result do you need?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses guys. The problem I was having was that my page would take too long to load - this was mainly because of how I had my foreach loops coded - performing far too much data manipulation on each cycle, rather than doing it all before I entered it into the database - making the display much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

`table_photos.aid` appears to be a foriegn key to `table_albums.aid`.  You can join the first two tables like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_photos
JOIN table_albums USING(aid)
```

But I don't see any obvious relationships to the third table `table_feed`, so maybe you should handle that query by looping in the script.

The first step will be to figure how how this data is related, then the second step is to write the code to form the data structure.